# Delegate UICollectionView to UITableViewCell to UIViewController

Tags: swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, delegates, google-maps-sdk-ios

What is the proper way to call a function in a UIViewController from a UICollectionViewCell that is in a UITableViewCell in the view controller?

More info:

I am brand new to Swift and IOS so please bear with me.  I have a UICollectionView inside a UITableViewCell inside a UIViewController.  The View Controller has a google map (GMSMapView).   I would like to add a marker to the map based on some info in the uicollectionview but am having issues accessing the correct mapView instance.  It seems every-time I try to add a marker, it is adding to an instance that does not exist. From what I have read, it sounds like using delegates is the proper path forward, however I have been unable to figure out the right combination.

Comment: IMHO don’t use a collection view inside a table view cell. It is an over kill. Either use a UIStackView inside a UITableViewCell or just use a `UICollectionView` instead of `UITableView` (`UICollectionView` can be customised to your needs)

Comment: Do a prototype with a simple example for UITableView first to understand how it works before doing the above stated. Also read the documentation. Then do a prototype for `UICollectionView`, then do one for `UIStackView`. Then you will be in a better position. Don’t attempt all at once if it is your first time

Comment: Closing this as it was solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28135579/call-function-in-view-controller-from-uitableviewcell